# Closing a Tkinter popup automatically without closing the main window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a GUI for a project and my supervisor requested that I include a progress bar as each iteration of the program can take up to 7 minutes.

I want the progress bar to pop up in a separate window, and close after the process is finished but, with my current understanding, either I have to close the popup manually or the whole GUI closes at once.

This is a simplified version of the code I'm using

```
import Tkinter as tk
from ttk import Progressbar
from os import listdir
import threading
import time
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TCC Image Processing")



def create_tcc(input_bar, input_progress_dialog):


    input_bar['maximum'] = 5
    input_bar['value'] = 0
    for x in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        input_bar['value'] += 1
    # this line is where the touble seems to be
    input_progress_dialog.destroy()


def run_tcc():
    progress_dialog = tk.Toplevel()
    progress_dialog.title("TCC Processing")

    bar = Progressbar(progress_dialog, orient="horizontal", length=500, value=0, mode="determinate")
    bar.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)
    t = threading.Thread(target=create_tcc, args=(bar, progress_dialog))
    t.start()
tcc_run_button = tk.Button(root, text="RUN", command=lambda:run_tcc())
tcc_run_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If possible I would like to avoid downloading extra modules that don't come with straight python.

Comment: Aside: the similarity of the names global `root`, `run_tcc.root2`, and `create_tcc.root` is confusing. Since neither of the local variables actually refer to the app's primary window, maybe choose another variable name, like `progress_dialog`?

Comment: Your code, in its current edited form, works perfectly for me. Precisely what problem do you have with it now?

Comment: The code above runs, and when I click the button a popup appears with a progress bar. The bar steps four times, and then stops, when it should be stepping five times. The only time it stepped five times with the current version of the code the program crashed, and a new popup appeared saying a problem was encountered.

Comment: I think the program crashes because `tkinter` is single threaded and you are trying to put it into two threads

Answer (score 2):

Call `.destroy()` to `progress_dialog` after the task is finished.

```
progress_dialog.destroy()
```

This will safely quit the popup without killing the whole application.

Comment: For me using .destroy() causes the progress bar to load to 80%, then stop and remain open.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necro but I came across this and found the answer and wanted to share in case others run into it.

At the exact moment the progress bar reaches its 5 second lifespan the window closes. The bar **does** load to 100%, you might need to take a recording and slow it down, but it definitely hits 100%. The problem is that because the window hits 100% at the exact same millisecond it gets destroyed, it looks like it doesn't make it.

Adding `time.sleep(.5)` before your `input_progress_dialog.destroy()` fixes the perceived failure point.

Code below is for Python 2, for 3, change `import Tkinter as tk` to `import tkinter as tk` and `from ttk import Progressbar` to `from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar`

```
import Tkinter as tk
from ttk import Progressbar
from os import listdir
import threading
import time
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TCC Image Processing")



def create_tcc(input_bar, input_progress_dialog):


    input_bar['maximum'] = 5
    input_bar['value'] = 0
    for x in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        input_bar['value'] += 1
    # this fixes it
    time.sleep(.5)
    input_progress_dialog.destroy()


def run_tcc():
    progress_dialog = tk.Toplevel()
    progress_dialog.title("TCC Processing")

    bar = Progressbar(progress_dialog, orient="horizontal", length=500, value=0, mode="determinate")
    bar.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)
    t = threading.Thread(target=create_tcc, args=(bar, progress_dialog))
    t.start()
tcc_run_button = tk.Button(root, text="RUN", command=lambda:run_tcc())
tcc_run_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the program crashes because `tkinter` is single threaded and you are trying to put it into two threads. Anyway on python 3.x it does not crash for me